# Regex split on parentheses getting double results

Tags: c#, regex

Im taking a string like "4 + 5 + ( 7 - 9 ) + 8" and trying to split on the parentheses to get a list containing 4 + 5, (7-9), + 8. So im using the regex string below. But it is giving me  4 + 5, (7-9), 7-9 , + 8. Hoping its just something easy. Thanks.

```
 List<string> test = Regex.Split("4 + 5 + ( 7 - 9 ) + 8", @"(\(([^)]+)\))").ToList();
```

Comment: What about the `+` after `4 + 5` ?

Comment: On the off-chance you're trying to evaluate the expression by parsing it, you might want to look at the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm).

Comment: oh yea the plus with the first group. Thank you guys was just the extra set of parentheses. And that article is interesting might be a better way to do this assignment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the extra set of parenthesis you have in your regex:

```
(\(([^)]+)\)) // your regex
(           ) // outer parens
 \(       \)  // literal parens match
   (     )    // extra parens you don't need
    [^)]+     // one or more 'not right parens'
```

The extra parens create a match for 'inside the literal parens', which is the extra `7 - 9` you see.

So you should have:

```
@"(\([^)]+\))"
```

Comment: That did it thanks for the explanation too helps me get a little more understanding. Will accept answer when it lets me in couple mins.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<string> test = Regex.Split("4 + 5 + ( 7 - 9 ) + 8", @"(\([^)]+\))").ToList();
```